# PowerShell script problem, cause of lacking knowledge

Tags: powershell, automation

I have kinda 0 expirience of coding but wanted to get myself a script which would take some work of me.'
Started this yesterday and just googled myself everything together.

What I want to do is open a vnc viewer(remote desktop app for our raspberrys), copy paste a link there, log into the website, fullscreen it and leave the session of vnc viwer, go into the next pi (we have 6 different where we need to do this every 3 hours) and do exactly the same.

I get everything together just with simple phrases like:

```
$wshell.SendKeys("{TAB}")
$wshell.SendKeys("{Enter}")
```

etc. but the only problem I have no is to close the session of vncviewer without killing the overview console(both have different tasks in task manager but named the same, only different is the ProcessID but this is changing for every start.

I figured out myself 3 different solutions but couldn't find a working answer on this in different forums or tech discords.

1. LF a command like" (`New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell).AppActivate((Kill-Process vncviewer).MainWindowTitle`) " which would kill only the vncviewer which is the main window atm (normaly this command is exactly the same only swap "`Kill-Process`" for "get-process" but I just wrote kill process to better descripe what Im looking for) and would leave the overview console open.
2. Get a command like .SendKeys for MouseClicks so I could work with fix "Set mouse coordinate" commands in PowerShell and then just simulate a mouseclick to close the window.
3. Do a "Get-Process | Out-File" and a "Get-Content" in the next line to write and read the processes which are running atm, to terminate the ProcessID of the session of nvcviewer to kill it via "Stop-Process "ProcessID"".
   But couldnt find a command for "Get-Content | Where-Object_Name = "nvcviewer"" or smth like this to know what ProcessID its running atm, problem would be I would get 2 process IDs without knowing which one to kill.

Would be great to get some help on this, sorry for my bad english/grammar its not my native language and I'm rly new to coding etc so if you have a answer for me would be great to get this explained for an 5year old ^^ + I'm not allowed to install 3rd party software so all needs to be in PowerShell.

Comment: Looking at your option 3 in order to get the process Id for a running process you don't have to write the output of Get-Process to a file.   If you pipe to Where-Object you can accomplish what you are looking for.   Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.ProcessName -like "nvcviewer"}  | Select-Object Id.   You can even pipe the result of the where-object right to Stop-Process, Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.ProcessName -like "nvcviewer"} | Stop-Process

Comment: Thanks for this but how u can difference the 2 running tasks? both are called the same only the id is different, I need to seperate them to close the session not the overwie. You know a way to start a process and give it a special name like "vncoverwiev" so I could seperate them per names.